# Blurry iOS7 TableViewCell contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

Since updating my app to iOS7, I've struggled with some blurry elements.

In particular, in one custom cell, all the `UILabel`s and `UISlider` appear blurred. 
I am setting the frames with integer values, so I presume sub-pixel rendering isn't coming from the cell layout itself, but something to do with a superview?

The custom cell is naturally inside a `UITableView`, which is full-screen aside from a nav bar, and is in a modal view.

```
- (void)reuseCellWithQuestion:(Question *)currentQuestion  {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    for (UIView *eachView in self.contentView.subviews) {
        [eachView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    NSString *currentQuestionTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@", currentQuestion.questionNumber, currentQuestion.body];
    NSArray *optionsArray = [currentQuestion.answerLabels componentsSeparatedByString:kPLAnswerLabelSeparator];

    int headerFontSize = 20;
    int labelFontSize = 16;
    UIFont *headerFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:headerFontSize];
    UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:labelFontSize];

    int totalWidth = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]>2) ? 1024 : 768;
    int leftMargin = 20;
    int topMargin = 20;
    int horizontalPadding = 10;
    int verticalPadding = 10;

    int headerWidth = totalWidth - leftMargin*2;
    int headerHeight = 40;
    int labelWidth = 200;
    int labelHeight = 60;
    int sliderWidth = totalWidth - leftMargin*2 - labelWidth*2 - horizontalPadding*2;
    int sliderHeight = labelHeight;

    CGRect headerLabelFrame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin, headerWidth, headerHeight));
    CGRect leftLabelFrame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin + headerHeight + verticalPadding, labelWidth, labelHeight));
    CGRect rightLabelFrame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(leftMargin + labelWidth + horizontalPadding*2 + sliderWidth, topMargin + headerHeight + verticalPadding, labelWidth, labelHeight));
    CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(leftMargin + labelWidth + horizontalPadding, topMargin + headerHeight + verticalPadding, sliderWidth, sliderHeight));

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerLabelFrame];
    headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    headerLabel.text = currentQuestionTitle;
    headerLabel.font = headerFont;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    UILabel *leftLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:leftLabelFrame];
    leftLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    leftLabel.text = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    leftLabel.font = labelFont;
    leftLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    leftLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:leftLabel];
    [leftLabel release];

    UILabel *rightLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rightLabelFrame];
    rightLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    rightLabel.text = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:1];
    rightLabel.font = labelFont;
    rightLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    rightLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:rightLabel];
    [rightLabel release];

    UISlider *tempSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
    tempSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tempSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tempSlider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor plColor];
    tempSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:tempSlider];
    self.theSlider = tempSlider;
    [tempSlider release];
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here? I've tried using `CGRectIntegral` from both within the `cellFromRowWithIndexPath` method and from the custom cell code too.

Appreciate any help.

---

Edit: screenshot below
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with blurry text?

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: Doesn't look very blurry to me. Can you take another screenshot with "Color misaligned images" turned on?

Comment: I see two possible case: one labels magically stay and overlap each time or second there is layer with enabled `shouldRasterize` that broke font sharp

Comment: Check [iOs 7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Controls.html) "Label" section.

Comment: I've added the second screenshot as requested.